# Pointer to pointer to an object COM method argument

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, atl

I am kinda new to COM/ATL stuff. Can not understand what to do with ** COM method argument in C#.

For example. Lets say I have an interface file Element.idl:

```
interface IElement : IDispatch
{
    [propget,
        id(1),
        helpstring("Gets the Root instance object")
    ]
    HRESULT InstanceRoot([out, retval]IRoot** ppRoot);
}
```

`IRoot` is also COM interface

```
interface IRoot : IDispatch
{
    [id(1),helpstring("Very important thing")]
    HRESULT Foo();
}
```

`IElement::InstanceRoot` getter implementation looks like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CElementObject::get_InstanceRoot(IRoot** ppRoot)
{
        *ppRoot = NULL;
        CComRoot* pRoot = CComRoot::GetRoot(); //Root is a singleton
        if (pRoot)
        {
            pRoot->QueryInterface(IID_IRoot, (void**)ppRoot);
        }
    }
    return NOERROR;
}
```

In C# I got `IntPtr` as an `Element.InstanceRoot` property type. How to convert this `IntPtr` into a reference to `Root` object (as I need to call `Root.Foo` method from my C# code)?

```
// Doesn't work. Can not convert System.IntPtr to MyLib.Root
Root tempRoot = someElement.InstanceRoot as Root;
```

**Update:** Forgot to mention that I am getting compilation error:

> "At least one of the arguments for 'Element.get_InstanceRoot' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate."

Why does it happen?

Comment: You can get `InstanceRoot` as object/interface pointer on C# side, your getting `IntPtr` means something is wrong. Something with type library perhaps, there is no indication in the code snippets what is wrong exactly.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for noticing. I forgot to add that I'am getting "At least one of the arguments for 'Element.get_InstanceRoot' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate." So yes, actually its my problem.

Comment: I would start with inspection of type library you create. If you see anything suspicious there, no wonder C# imports it already incomplete and you have to fix the problem on the other side then.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for advise! Can you be so kind to prompt any popular way to inspect the type library? I am new to this, so have no idea how to do that. If I run tlbimp tool I see same errors. Object Browser also not helping much (I can see that InstanceRoot property has type IntPtr but why did it happen?) How interop generator works? And why did he failed to translate my return type correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, [COM/OLE Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx) in Windows SDK, \bin\x86\oleview.exe. Open your ATL binary (menu File, View TypeLib...) and see what's in there.

Comment: Thank you very mych @RomanR. That helped me a lot! Problem solved!